# Why does the variable, passed as an address to a function, not change its value even if the value is changed in the function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

So, I passed the address of a variable to a particular function. And I changed the value of the variable using pointers inside the function, the change is reflected when I print the variable in the function. But when I print it in the main() block after calling the function, it doesn't reflect the same value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int result_count;
  int* result = waiter(n, number, q, &result_count);
  printf("%d",result_count);  //prints 0
}
int* waiter(int number_count, int* number, int q, int* result_count) 
{
  int t=10;
  result_count=&t;
  printf("\n%d",*result_count); //prints 10
}
```

So this is the code, and I tried assigning the value of "t" to "result_count", but in the main block, the value prints as 0 or just a random number.

Comment: Change `result_count=&t;` to `*result_count = t;`

Comment: Also remember to declare the function `waiter` *before* you call it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't work either. There is a segmentation fault if I do `*result_count = t;` , before assigning `result_count=&t;` . I am actually running this code on Hackerrank, so that could be an issue.

Comment: This works on visual studio code, but throws errors on hackerrank. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the parameter `result_count` is local variable of function `waiter()`. Any change in it's value will reflect within `waiter()` function body.
If you want to change the value of the variable whose address `result_count` variable is holding, then de-reference it and assign the value:

```
*result_count = t;
```

De-referencing `result_count` mean your program is accessing the memory of variable whose address `result_count` pointer variable is holding.

---

For better understanding:

Initially when `waiter()` function called, pointer `result_count` pointing to memory of argument passed to `waiter()`:

```
waiter()                  main()
result_count              result_count (assume it's address is 100) 
        +-----+             +-----+
        | 100 |------------>|     |
        +-----+             +-----+
```

After this statement -
`result_count=&t;`

```
waiter()                  main()
result_count              result_count (assume it's address is 100) 
        +-----+             +-----+
        | 200 |----+        |     |
        +-----+    |        +-----+
                   |
                   |        waiter()
                   |        t       (assume it's address is 200) 
                   |        +-----+
                   +------->|     |
                            +-----+
```

Instead, when you do - `*result_count = t;`

```
waiter()                  main()
result_count              result_count (assume it's address is 100) 
        +-----+             +-----+
        | 100 |------------>|  10 |
        +-----+             +-----+
```

Hence, after returning from `waiter()`, when your program print `result_count`, it print the value assigned in the `waiter()` function.